# Spring Data MongoDB support for inheritance on a nested object

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

So My problem is related to how spring handles inheritance when it comes to fields.

I have four classes

```
@Document(collection = "A")
public class A {
    @Id
    id;

    @Field
    B data;
}

public class B {
    Type type
}

public class C extends B {
    String cField;

    public C() {
         super(Type.C);    
    }
}

public class D extends B {
    Integer dField;

    public D() {
         super(Type.D);    
    }
}
```

I'm able to store data into mongodb using this schema and it looks something like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f291f861020d19a3db05123"),
    "data" : {
        "cField" : "abcd", 
        "type" : "C", 
        "_class" : "com.example.C"
    }, 
    "_class" : "com.example.A"
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f291f861020d19a3db05124"), 
    "data" : {
        "dField" : NumberInt(30), 
        "type" : "D", 
        "_class" : "com.example.D"
    }, 
    "_class" : "com.example.A"
}
```

Now when I try to do a findAll on repository, it does not casts to the child class, but simply returns an instance of B.
What changes do I need to make so that I can get correct child object when getting from db?

Comment: Can you provide your repository code ?

Comment: Given example is a simplified version of a larger codebase. unfortunately, the code base is private.